# Getting both TF.exe and Query TFS in Windows container

Tags: docker, tfs

I have two docker files.  One allows me to Query TFS using $versionControlServer.QueryHistory.   The second allows me to use tf.exe to pull code down from the server make modifications to Version.html file and check in the changes.  I would like to have one docker file that can do both,  Query TFS and Modify code.   I am having problems doing this.   First off one docker file is using microsoft/windowservercode:10.0.14393.1480 and the other one is using microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.7.1

Here is the code for doing a Query against TFS

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore:10.0.14393.1480

# Setup shell
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

# Note: Add NuGet
RUN Invoke-WebRequest "https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe" -OutFile "C:\windows\nuget.exe" -UseBasicParsing

RUN Mkdir LoadClient
COPY powershell \LoadClient
```

Here is the psm1 file to load the TFS Assemblies

```
    Write-Host "Loading InstallTFSClient"
#Module location folder
$TFSClientRoot = "C:\TFSClient"
#where to put TFS Client OM files
$NugetFolder = "$TFSClientRoot\Nuget\"
$BinFolder = $("$TFSClientRoot\bin\")

# TFS Object Model Assembly Names
$vsCommon = "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common"
$commonName = "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common"
$clientName = "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client"
$VCClientName = "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client"
$WITClientName = "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client"
$BuildClientName = "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client"
$BuildCommonName = "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Common" 

$Source =  @"
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using  Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using System.Net;
public class ConnectByImplementingCredentialsProvider : ICredentialsProvider
    {
        public ICredentials GetCredentials(Uri uri, ICredentials iCredentials)
        {
            return new NetworkCredential("OurUser", "OurPassword", "OurEnv");
        }

        public void NotifyCredentialsAuthenticated(Uri uri)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Unable to authenticate");
        }
    }
"@

#============================================================================
# new folder method
#============================================================================
function New-Folder{
    param( [Parameter( Mandatory=$true)]  $folderPath
           )

    if (Test-Path( $folderPath ))
    {
        Remove-Item $folderPath -Force -Recurse
    }

    mkdir $folderPath
}



#============================================================================
# Get-TfsAssembliesFromNuget method
#============================================================================
function Get-TfsAssembliesWithNuget{

    New-Folder $TFSClientRoot
    New-Folder $NugetFolder
    New-Folder $BinFolder

    #get all of the TFS 2015 Object Model packages from nuget
    C:\windows\nuget install "Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client" -Version 14.83.0 -OutputDirectory $NugetFolder -ExcludeVersion -NonInteractive
    C:\windows\nuget install "Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient" -Version 14.83.0 -OutputDirectory $NugetFolder -ExcludeVersion -NonInteractive
    C:\windows\nuget install "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client" -Version 14.83.0 -OutputDirectory $NugetFolder -ExcludeVersion -NonInteractive
    C:\windows\nuget install "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.InteractiveClient" -Version 14.83.0 -OutputDirectory $NugetFolder -ExcludeVersion -NonInteractive

    #Copy all of the required .dlls out of the nuget folder structure 
    #to a bin folder so we can reference them easily and they are co-located
    #so that they can find each other as necessary when loading
    $allDlls = Get-ChildItem -Path $NugetFolder -Recurse -File -Filter "*.dll"

    # Create list of all the required .dlls
    #exclude portable dlls
    #$net45Dlls = $allDlls | ? {$_.PSPath.Contains("portable") -ne $true } | ? {$_.PSPath.Contains("resources") -ne $true } | ? { ($_.PSPath.Contains("net45") -eq $true) -or ($_.PSPath.Contains("native") -eq $true) -or ($_.PSPath.Contains("Microsoft.ServiceBus") -eq $true) }
    $requiredDlls = $allDlls | Where-Object {$_.PSPath.Contains("portable") -ne $true } | where-object {$_.PSPath.Contains("resources") -ne $true } | where-object { ($_.PSPath.Contains("net45") -eq $true) -or ($_.PSPath.Contains("native") -eq $true) -or ($_.PSPath.Contains("Microsoft.ServiceBus") -eq $true) }

    #exclude resource dlls
    $requiredDlls = $requiredDlls | Where-Object {$_.PSPath.Contains("resources") -ne $true } 
    #include net45, native, and Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll
    $requiredDlls = $requiredDlls | Where-Object { ($_.PSPath.Contains("net45") -eq $true) -or ($_.PSPath.Contains("native") -eq $true) -or ($_.PSPath.Contains("Microsoft.ServiceBus") -eq $true) }
    #copy them all to a bin folder
    $requiredDlls | ForEach-Object  { Copy-Item -Path $_.Fullname -Destination $BinFolder}

}

#============================================================================
# Install-TfsAssembliesFromDisk method
#============================================================================
function Install-TfsAssembliesFromDisk{
    Write-Host "loading TFS assemblies"

    $TestVar = $($BinFolder + $vsCommon + ".dll")
    write-host $TestVar

    try {
        Add-Type -LiteralPath $($BinFolder  + $vsCommon + ".dll")
        Add-Type -LiteralPath $($BinFolder  +  $commonName + ".dll")
        Add-Type -LiteralPath $($BinFolder  +  $clientName + ".dll")

        Add-Type -LiteralPath $($BinFolder  +  $clientName + ".dll")
        $Assem = ("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")
        Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies $Assem -TypeDefinition $Source -Language CSharp 

        Add-Type -LiteralPath $($BinFolder  +  $VCClientName + ".dll")
        Add-Type -LiteralPath $($BinFolder  +  $WITClientName + ".dll")
        Add-Type -LiteralPath $($BinFolder  +  $BuildClientName + ".dll")
        Add-Type -LiteralPath $($BinFolder  +  $BuildCommonName + ".dll")
    } 
    catch {
        $_.Exception.LoaderExceptions | ForEach-Object  { $_.Message }
    }
}


Get-TfsAssembliesWithNuget
Install-TfsAssembliesFromDisk here
```

Here is the powershell that needs to run on the container to activate everything.

```
#============================================================================
# Setup TFS stuff
#============================================================================
function Setup-Tfs {
    # Get TFS nuget packages installed
    Import-Module C:\LoadClient\InstallTFSClient.psm1

    # Connect to TFS
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client") | out-null
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client") | out-null

    $tfsServer =  "http://OurUrl:Port/etc...";
    $tfs = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationServerFactory]::GetServer($tfsServer, (New-Object ConnectByImplementingCredentialsProvider)) 
    $Script:versionControlServer = $tfs.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer] ) 
    $Script:recursionType = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.RecursionType]::Full

}
```

Here is the docker file to load tf.exe

```
# escape=`

# Use the latest Windows Server Core image with .NET Framework 4.7.1.
FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.7.1

# Download the Build Tools bootstrapper.
ADD https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vs_buildtools.exe C:\TEMP\vs_buildtools.exe

# Install Build Tools excluding workloads and components with known issues.
RUN C:\TEMP\vs_buildtools.exe --quiet --wait --norestart --nocache `
    --installPath C:\BuildTools `
    --all `
    --remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.10240 `
    --remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.10586 `
    --remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.14393 `
    --remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows81SDK `
 || IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="3010" EXIT 0

# Start developer command prompt with any other commands specified.
ENTRYPOINT C:\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat 

# Default to PowerShell if no other command specified.
CMD ["powershell.exe", "-NoLogo", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"]
```

Any help on getting this to one docker file would be greatly appricated.

Comment: Did your just want to use a single powershell script to query the files' history and pull down the history files?

Comment: Almost I wanted to query TFS for WI that are part of an iteration.   I would also like to check out and edit files from TFS.    I would also like to find the history from TFS for a file.